# Wordpress Template System not working with get_template_part

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I am designing a wordpress theme using the Underscore theme as a base. I have created a custom post type called Projects. Here's the code that registers the post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'Projects',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'projects' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'projects' )
            ),
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt'),
        )
    );
}
```

So, now that I created a new post type, I went to go design the template for the post type. Since Underscore uses get_template_type to pull the theme together, I made one file called **single-projects.php** which includes the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @package professional1d
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'Projects' ); ?>

                <?php professional1d_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

                <?php
                    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                    if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
                        comments_template();
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And then I created the **content-projects.php** page which has the code for the actual template, which is:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package professional1d
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php professional1d_posted_on(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <p>
            <img src="<?php
                $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size', true);
                echo $thumb_url[0];
                        ?>" class="img-thumbnail" align="left">
            <strong><u><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></u></strong><br>
            <strong>Date: </strong> 
                <?php the_field('start_date'); ?>
                <?php
                    if(get_field('end_date')){
                        echo ' - ' . get_field('end_date') .;
                    }
                ?><br>
            <strong>Type: </strong> <?php the_field('type'); ?><br>
            <strong>Status: </strong> <?php the_field('status'); ?>
        </p>
        <div class="sexy_line"></div>

        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'professional1d' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <?php
            /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
            $category_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'professional1d' ) );

            /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
            $tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', __( ', ', 'professional1d' ) );

            if ( ! professional1d_categorized_blog() ) {
                // This blog only has 1 category so we just need to worry about tags in the meta text
                if ( '' != $tag_list ) {
                    $meta_text = __( 'This entry was tagged %2$s. Bookmark the <a href="%3$s" title="Permalink to %4$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.', 'professional1d' );
                } else {
                    $meta_text = __( 'Bookmark the <a href="%3$s" title="Permalink to %4$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.', 'professional1d' );
                }

            } else {
                // But this blog has loads of categories so we should probably display them here
                if ( '' != $tag_list ) {
                    $meta_text = __( 'This entry was posted in %1$s and tagged %2$s. Bookmark the <a href="%3$s" title="Permalink to %4$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.', 'professional1d' );
                } else {
                    $meta_text = __( 'This entry was posted in %1$s. Bookmark the <a href="%3$s" title="Permalink to %4$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.', 'professional1d' );
                }

            } // end check for categories on this blog

            printf(
                $meta_text,
                $category_list,
                $tag_list,
                get_permalink(),
                the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' )
            );
        ?>

        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'professional1d' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post-## -->

</div>
```

I think I followed the correct protocol to make template work, but for some reason, when I open one of the Project posts, a page with the content of the post does appear, but it's not using the template I designed in the **content-projects.php** file. You can see the issue in action here: http://onedirectionconnection.com/tester/?projects=take-me-home-tour As you can see, the template I pasted above is not being used.

Also, I tried lowercasing the P in Projects in the single-projects.php file, but then the content after the header just disappears.

The single.php and content-single.php use the same method and it's working for that pair. Would anyone be able to offer me some insight into what I am doing wrong?

Let me know if you need any more information or code!

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things first:

`register_post_type($post_type, $args)`:

> $post_type
>   (string) (required) Post type. (max. 20 characters, ***can not contain capital letters or spaces***)
>   Default: None

Given that, your

```
register_post_type( 'Projects',...
```

should be

```
register_post_type( 'projects',...
```

You can use the `labels` array to create properly capitalized names.

```
'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Projects' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Project' )
),
```

Your custom template file names should all be lowercase as well as your `get_template_part` calls like `get_template_part( 'content', 'projects' );`

Also make sure you update your permalinks structure (just re-save) once you made changes to your custom post type init code.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I made those changes (changed the Projects to lowercase and then changed it in the functions file as well). But now when you go to a project page, only the header displays: http://onedirectionconnection.com/tester/projects/take-me-home-tour/

Comment: Maybe it's the permalinks... Did you mean change the permalinks in the back end under setting >> Permalinks? And if so, which permalink structure do you mean?

Comment: You don't have to change your permalink structure, just re-save what you have in Settings->Permalinks.

Comment: I've re-saved the permalinks, but still the same issue (only header showing).

Comment: You have a PHP error somewhere after `<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">`, the whole template gets cut off there. You can enable error reporting by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your `functions.php`, right below the `<?php` call and then check if you get any errors printed.

Comment: I enabled the error log, refreshed the page and then opened the error log file in my theme's folder. The only errors were from last month: [11-Sep-2013 03:51:19 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/undersco/public_html/content/themes/underscoresme-github/plugins/underscoresme-generator/prototype/index.php on line 14

Comment: It's just strange because the error would have to be the loop: <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> since it cuts off right under main, but it doesn't seem to make sence since there's definitely posts in the Projects section...

Comment: Also change in your `wp-config.php` `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` if PHP doesn't print any errors. There is definitively an error (regardless of having posts or not).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38653/discussion-between-peter-michael-and-noelle)